# Adaptive scan of function concurrently

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, multiprocessing

This function try to scan the given function in n dimensions in the given range by adaptively divide the area into n+1 points polygon (e.g. triangle in 2D; tetrahedron in 3D)

I tried to seperate the implementation of splitting/initializing, as it would be easier to apply it on other cases (e.g. square lattice scan, discrete scan, tree scan, etc..)

async_scan.py

```
from initializer import RecursiveBoundaryCentreInitializer
from solver import Solver
from explorer import Explorer
from splitter import LargestDisputeLineSplitter


def async_scan(executor, initializer, splitter, func, *iterables):
    solver = Solver(executor, func)
    explorer = Explorer(solver, splitter)
    for points in initializer(iterables):
        explorer.register(points)

    for point, future in solver:
        exception = future.exception()
        result = future.result() if exception is None else exception
        yield point, result
        explorer.trigger(point)


def async_surface_scan(executor, tol, func, *iterables):
    initializer = RecursiveBoundaryCentreInitializer()
    splitter = LargestDisputeLineSplitter(tol)
    return async_scan(executor, initializer, splitter, func, *iterables)


def example():
    from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as Executor
    from math import atan2 as func

    with Executor() as executor:
        x = y = (-1, 3)
        results = async_surface_scan(executor, 0.03, func, x, y)
        for (x, y), f in results:
            print(x, y, f)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    example()
```

explorer.py

```
from collections import defaultdict
from concurrent.futures import Future


class Explorer(object):

    def __init__(self, solver, splitter):
        self.solver = solver
        self.splitter = splitter
        self.registry = defaultdict(set)

    def register(self, points):
        job = Job(self.solver, points)
        for point in points:
            self.registry[point].add(job)

    def trigger(self, point):
        queue = self.registry[point]
        while queue:
            job = queue.pop()
            if not job.done():
                continue

            for p in job.points:
                self.registry[p].discard(job)
            for points in self.split(job):
                self.register(points)

    def split(self, job):
        points = job.points
        exceptions = job.exception()
        if exceptions is not None:
            return

        results = job.result()
        return self.splitter(points, results)


class Job(Future):

    def __init__(self, solver, points):
        self.points = points
        self.futures = tuple(map(solver, points))

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.points)

    def cancel(self):
        return all(f.cancel() for f in self.futures)

    def cancelled(self):
        return all(f.cancelled() for f in self.futures)

    def running(self):
        return any(f.running() for f in self.futures)

    def done(self):
        return all(f.done() for f in self.futures)

    def result(self, timeout=None):
        return tuple(f.result(timeout) for f in self.futures)

    def exception(self, timeout=None):
        exceptions = (f.exception(timeout) for f in self.futures)
        exceptions = tuple(e for e in exceptions if e is not None)
        if len(exceptions) < 1:
            return None
        return exceptions
```

solver.py

```
from collections import ChainMap
from concurrent.futures import as_completed
from bidict import bidict


class Solver(object):

    def __init__(self, executor, func):
        self.fresh    = bidict()
        self.done     = dict()
        self.cache    = ChainMap(self.fresh, self.done)
        self.func     = func
        self.executor = executor

    def __call__(self, args):
        if args not in self.cache:
            self.fresh[args] = self.executor.submit(self.func, *args)
        return self.cache[args]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if not self.fresh:
            raise StopIteration

        future = as_completed(self.fresh.values())
        future = next(iter(future))
        args   = self.fresh.inv[future]

        self.done[args] = self.fresh.pop(args)
        return args, future
```

initializer.py

```
from itertools import chain, tee, product
from statistics import mean


def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b)
    yield from zip(a, b)


def selection(seq):
    for i, x in enumerate(seq):
        yield i, x, seq[:i] + seq[i+1:]


def iappend(iterable, x):
    return chain(iterable, [x])


class RecursiveBoundaryCentreInitializer(object):
    """
    Given cuts for n dimensions, generate polygon with n+1 points,
    each containing two point on the boundary, one point on the centre
    of the sides, one point on the centre of the volumes, etc...
    """
    @classmethod
    def __call__(cls, iterables):
        xs = list(map(tuple, iterables))
        return cls.reduce(xs)

    @classmethod
    def reduce(cls, xs):
        if len(xs) <= 1:
            yield from pairwise((x,) for x in xs[0])
            return

        c = tuple(map(mean, xs))
        for i, y, zs in selection(xs):
            for j, z in product(y, cls.reduce(zs)):
                t = tuple(p[:i] + (j,) + p[i:] for p in z)
                yield tuple(iappend(t, c))


def example():
    initializer = RecursiveBoundaryCentreInitializer()
    for points in initializer([range(2), range(2), range(2)]):
        print(points)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    example()
```

splitter.py

```
from itertools import combinations, repeat
from statistics import mean
from numpy.linalg import matrix_rank
from numpy import array


class LargestDisputeLineSplitter(object):
    """
    Given polygon with n+1 points in n dimensions,
    Split the polygon at the side with largest diff. result,
    Check the splitted polygon for closeness and collinearity.
    """

    def __init__(self, tol):
        self.tol = tol

    def __call__(self, points, results):
        pairs = combinations(zip(points, results), 2)
        pairs = ((abs(r0 - r1), (p0, p1)) for (p0, r0), (p1, r1) in pairs)
        diff, pairs = max(pairs)
        if diff < self.tol:
            return ()

        mid  = tuple(map(mean, zip(*pairs)))
        old  = tuple(p for p in points if p not in pairs)
        news = zip(pairs, repeat(mid))
        groups = (old + new for new in news)
        groups = map(list, groups)
        groups = map(self.remove_close, groups)
        groups = map(self.remove_colinear, groups)
        groups = (points for points in groups if len(points) > 1)
        groups = map(tuple, groups)
        return tuple(groups)

    def remove_close(self, points):
        while True:
            for x, y in combinations(points, 2):
                if any(abs(i-j) > self.tol for i, j in zip(x, y)):
                    continue
                points.remove(y)
                break
            else:
                return points

    def remove_colinear(self, points):
        while True:
            for three in combinations(points, 3):
                T  = array(three)
                T -= T[0, :]
                if matrix_rank(T, self.tol) > 1:
                    continue
                mid = sorted(three)[1]
                points.remove(mid)
                break
            else:
                return points
```

Comment: What is your question ?